# Swing apllication throws java.lang.NullPointerException on ActionEvent

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I am making a Java Swing application which contains 1 TextArea, 1 Label and 1 TextField.

My Code is the following:

```
package mainpack.newboston;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    protected JTextArea textarea123;
    protected JTextField textfield1;
    JLabel label;
    JFrame frame;

    public Panel() {
        setLayout(null);

        JTextArea textarea123 = new JTextArea();
        JTextField textfield1 = new JTextField(30);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Command: ");

        add(textarea123);
        add(textfield1);
        add(label);

        // textarea123.append("Hello");
        textarea123.setEditable(false);
        textarea123.setSize(600, 600);
        textarea123.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        textarea123.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        textfield1.setBorder(null);
        textfield1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        textfield1.setForeground(Color.white);

        textfield1.addActionListener(this);
        textfield1.setActionCommand("commandexecuted");

        // label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        label.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

        //#######################################################
        Insets insets = getInsets();

        Dimension fieldsize = textfield1.getPreferredSize();
        textfield1.setBounds(63 + insets.left, 555 + insets.top, 537, fieldsize.height);

        textfield1.setFocusable(true);
        textfield1.setEnabled(true);
        Dimension labelsize = label.getPreferredSize();
        label.setBounds(0 + insets.left, 555 + insets.top, labelsize.width, labelsize.height);

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Dimension size = textarea123.getPreferredSize();
        textarea123.setBounds(0 + insets.left, 0 + insets.top, 600, 555);
        //##########################################################
    }

    /**
      * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
      * this method should be invoked from the
      * event-dispatching thread.
      */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("New Boston");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Set up the content pane.
        frame.add(new Panel());
        //Size and display the window.
        Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(600 + insets.left + insets.right, 600 + insets.top + insets.bottom);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void ConsoleLog(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void textappend(String message) {
        textarea123.append(message);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("commandexecuted")) {
            if (textfield1.getText().equals("Try")) {
                ConsoleLog("Hello");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error message when enter is pressed while TextField is on focus:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mainpack.newboston.Panel.actionPerformed(Panel.java:127)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm trying to make it look like a console and use some commands, but I will do this later since i can't use ActionEvents...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor, change this line

```
JTextField textfield1 = new JTextField(30);
```

to

```
this.textfield1 = new JTextField(30);
```

Comment: Realy, so easy? i was trying to fix this hours... Many Thanks :))

Comment: Do same for your text area and label.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining fields such as `protected JTextField textfield1;`.

You are then defining local variables such as with `JTextField textfield1 = new JTextField(30);`.

So, for example, `textfield1` is your object (within local context), and `this.textfield1` is null because you never give it a value.

I suggest assigning a variable to your field like so:

`textfield1 = new JTextField(30);`

Try this technique with your fields, it both avoids assigning a local variable of the same name, and also avoids writing an implicit `this`, when assigning values.

I also suggest taking a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html